# How to sort category group by another column in SSRS line chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating line chart in a paginated SSRS report and my data consists of three columns and looks something like this:

```
Date       |   MonthYear   |   Percentage
20.09.2018 |   Sep 2018    |   29.8
29.09.2018 |   Sep 2018    |   87.5
30.01.2019 |   Jan 2019    |   18.3
```

For creating my line chart I need `Percentage` values per month so my dataset consists of only `Percentage` and `MonthYear`.

But I only need to visualize data for the last 10 months. What I have done so far is that I have created another dataset called `DateSource` containing the `Date` and `MonthYear` and filtered the rows such that I get data for the last 10 months.

And in the Category Groups of my line chart I am fetching data as `=Lookup(Fields!MonthYear.Value, Fields!MonthYear.Value, Fields!MonthYear.Value, "DateSoure")`. Here is what my chart looks like.

[image]

I am wondering how to write a lookup query to fetch only those data points whose corresponding `MonthYear` exist. Or if there's a better way to view data for only last 10 months.

I am new to SSRS and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by a workaround. In the original dataset I filtered the rows using `IN` operator and checked if `MonthYear` is one from the last 10 months. I used a `Split` method:
[image]

In the code snippet below I concatenate two strings, one containing month's name and another with the respective year. And then check if `MonthYear` exists `IN` any of these values.

```
=Split(
    StrConv(Format(DateAdd("M",-1,Now()),"MMM"), VbStrConv.ProperCase) & " " & Year(DateAdd("M",-1,Now())) 
    & "," & 
    StrConv(Format(DateAdd("M",-2,Now()),"MMM"), VbStrConv.ProperCase) & " " & Year(DateAdd("M",-2,Now())) 
    ...
    StrConv(Format(DateAdd("M",-10,Now()),"MMM"), VbStrConv.ProperCase) & " " & Year(DateAdd("M",-10,Now()))
    , ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I filter the rows to get data for the last 10 months but get percentage only as if I were aggregating on MonthYear? So far my Category Group Properties include the following group expression:

I would suggest do the aggregation within data-set query, so the `Group by [MonthYear]` would be taken care outside report, for the report it's already processed data, when you apply filter Months aggregation won't effected since the processed data going to have per month one-row.

In case if there is other element within report that required date-wise data, then you can crate new data-set that shows without `group by` and per date one-row.

P.S: If any help needed on doing aggregation within data-set, you may post your data-set query part of the question.

Screenshot reference for adding additional data-set:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Shekar. I actually need multiple visualisations with data only from the last 10 months so it can be useful to have a dataset containing only dates. 
How can link the new dataset that I create from ```Date``` in filters of rest of the datasets?

Comment: @zimmer, you can simply right click on **Datasets** folder to add additional data-set, each data-set can have different query. added screenshot in my answer for your reference

Comment: Thank you, @Shekar. I got that but what you said about "In case if there is other element within report that required date-wise data, then you can crate new data-set that shows without group by and per date one-row", how can I create a new dataset containing only dates and link to, for instance, Report Details and Report Stats?